What is wrong with my web server?
I am running a web server, and randomly I see messages like \x16\x03\x01 popping up. Here is what I am seeing.

My server is running Ubuntu 24.04. Also I am using a playit.gg tunnel so all the IPs start with 127.

One assumes you noted code 400 in your output and what that code means.

code 400, message Bad request version

There is likely nothing wrong with the server. These are web requests from a source looking for weak systems. My fleet of web servers receive millions of these every week and the most egregious IP addresses are blackholed to ensure system resources are preserved for legitimate uses.

What should I do then?
